# Baqend Speed Kit Plesk - Joomla Site Almost No Acceleration

Tags: joomla, plesk, baqend

I have a Joomla Site with Speed Kit for Plesk.

Before activating Speed Kit for the domain Speed Kit predicted a speed increase that would result in a loading time of around 500ms.

After activating Speed Kit the result is just a faktor of 1.1 to 1.8 depending whether I turn of a separate css and js acceleration plugin and the gzip compression within Joomla.

The page loading time is not near 500ms it's around 4 to 6 seconds.

Info: Newest Joomla version, PHP 7.3, around 25 elements to load with the Joomla compression plugin active and around 50 with it deactivated, page size around 2.5 MB.

Is there something I should check or configure to improve the result? Or is the acceleration generally not working so well with Joomla?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In case you’re using a website with personalized content (e.g. shopping carts) our default Speed Kit configuration excludes the HTML to ensure that everything still works properly for your customers. This happens automatically when you check the “Dynamic Site” checkbox during our installation wizard. Since the HTML is often the main bottleneck most of the possible improvements are obtainable here. In your case, including the HTML would be the main contributor in adding a performance uplift.

Assuming your website has personalized content: To fully exploit the potential of Speed Kit you need to use Dynamic Blocks. However, creating a Dynamic Block configuration requires some time and a professional developer.
In the following page you can read about how to include it and accelerate personalized content:

Dynamic Blocks: https://www.baqend.com/guide/topics/speed-kit/personalized/
In case you don’t have the support of a professional developer it is advised that you keep your HTML excluded. But as already mentioned, excluding the HTML and using Dynamic Blocks might only be necessary if you have personalized content, otherwise the HTML could be whitelisted for Speed Kit.

Comment: Good on you for supporting your product (well, the product that you contribute to) here.